# Firebase Algolia on 2 different collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, algolia

Im currently use Algolia on one collection, but i want to search in a another collection too separately, is there a way to add a second collection to Algolia

Answer (score 13):

You can install another instance of the same extension

Comment: Thanks, the route to installing was a bit hard to find, not that straight forward

Comment: @AakashRathee Can any of you share links or anything, for how to install multiple instances of extension in the same firestore project ?

Comment: Open the firebase console > Explore extensions > Search with Algolia > Install > Select the project you want to install the extensions.

Comment: When I add a secret for the API key using the extension wizard, it makes a new entry in secrets manager that's a duplicate of my first collection's API key. Is this typical, or is there some way to avoid this redundancy?